# Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but it is not installable

Tags: apt, package-management, kali-linux

trying to install freerdp `sudo apt-get install freerdp-x11`

I get error

> libfreerdp-codec1.1 : Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but it is not installable

I tried to install libjpeg8 `sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev`

> E: Package 'libjpeg8-dev' has no installation candidate

while trying to update i get

```
$ sudo apt-get update                                                                                                                                                                                                        1 ⚙
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu impish InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu xenial InRelease                            
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]                          
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu impish InRelease [17.5 kB]               
Hit:4 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease                                             
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu impish InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu impish InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu impish InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu impish InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: The dependency calls for `libjpeg8`, *not* `libjpeg8-dev` (which doesn’t exist). What does `sudo apt install libjpeg8` say?

Comment: @StephenKitt E: Package 'libjpeg8' has no installation candidate

Comment: @NasirRiley Kali linux

Comment: Welcome to the site. When asked for clarifications, please don't respond in comments, but edit your post to include the requested information. Reading through the comments is rather painful, and comments are subject to removal without notice by moderators.

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/655925/117549

Answer (score 2):

In Debian 9 and above, the classic `libjpeg8` has been replaced by `libjpeg-turbo`, which includes SIMD instruction support to achieve better performance (2-6x) with compatible processors.

Project homepage: https://www.libjpeg-turbo.org/

So if an old package requests `libjpeg8` but it is not available in Debian or any Debian-related distribution, you might try installing `libjpeg62-turbo` (or a higher version) instead. Although it is originally forked off the legacy libjpeg v6b codebase (which explains the version number), it also includes the ABIs of libjpeg v7 and v8, so it should be compatible.

This is not very obvious, so I thought to add this answer to an old question.

Comment: Note that the `libjpeg-turbo` package in Debian is built with v6b compatibility only, [not v7 or v8](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/libjpeg-turbo/-/blob/master/README.md#libjpeg-v7-and-v8-apiabi-emulation). Depending on which functions are actually used by applications, adding `libjpeg-turbo` can work, but adding symlinks to `libjpeg.so.8` etc. can cause subtle (or not-so-subtle) errors with applications expecting the v7 or v8 ABI. The Ubuntu package *is* built with v8 compatibility, but that’s not necessarily relevant here.

Comment: I originally intended the above as a comment on [Alex Stragies’ answer to another related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/739700/86440), but that was deleted, so I thought it would be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

On Kali Linux it is packaged under the `freerdp2-x11` name. It can be installed through:

```
sudo apt install freerdp2-x11
```

or `sudo apt isntall freerdp2`, the `freerdp2-x11` will be installed as dependency, [see freerdp2](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/freerdp2#).

But you should remove all third party repository before install the package:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Answer (score -1):

To install `libjpeg8-dev`, use this:

```bash
sudo apt install aptitude
sudo aptitude install libjpeg-dev
```

You may then need to choose "no", "yes", "yes". See my detailed instructions here: [How to install/upgrade to the latest version of Poppler/`pdftoppm` (version 22.11.0 at the time of this writing) on Linux Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74313286/4561887)

Comment: Could you say something about what the cause of the user's issue is and _why_ this would solve the issue that the user has?